# Android Nested Data Modeling

Tags: android, json, gson, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

I have the following contract

```
"shape": {
        "type": "MultiPoly",
        "points": [
            [
                [
                    [
                        -92.53941242522892,
                        41.51492979593705
                    ],
                    [
                        -92.53942433363545,
                        41.51493000420402
                    ],
.
.
.

"shape": {
      "type": "Poly",
      "points": [
          [
              [
                  -92.6814794540405,
                  41.7796968811509
              ],
              [
                  -92.6820158958435,
                  41.7801769167539
              ]
.
.
.
```

As you can see, `MultiPoly` has another level in the array hierarchy. How can I create a POJO to successfully parse both cases? Is it possible?

`List<List<List<Double>>> points;` seems to work but only for `Poly`s.

Thanks,
Otterman

Comment: could you put a complete json file? did you try using : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure this out by storing the `points` in a generic `Object []` array and then parsing manually based on the type.

`private Object[] points;`